# Audio playbackRate not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html5-audio

I'm trying to change the HTML5 audio player speed. Here's my code:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $document, ...) {

var audioPlayer0 = $document[0].getElementById("audioPlayer0");
console.log(audioPlayer0);
audioPlayer0.playbackRate = 0.5;
console.log(audioPlayer0.playbackRate);

};
```

Here's the log:

```
<audio controls preload=​"auto" id=​"audioPlayer0" ng-src=​"http:​/​/​audio.oxforddictionaries.com/​en/​mp3/​not_us_1.mp3">​…​</audio>​
0.5
```

AngularJS uses `$document` instead of `document`. `getElementById` is picking up the right element. The value of `playbackRate` is set. But the audio player continues to play at normal speed. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My HMTL audio player is in the template, and a button to click to slow the audio playback rate:

```js
<audio controls id="audioplayer{{$index}}" preload="auto" ng-src="{{pronunciation.audioFiles}}"></audio>

<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="slowAudio($index)">Slow</button>
</div>
```

The handler is in the controller:

```js
$scope.slowAudio = function(index) {
  let audioplayer = 'audioplayer' + index;
  document.getElementById(audioplayer).playbackRate = 0.5;
};
```

One problem was that the audio player loads later, after the page loads. The new code waits for the user to click the button before the handler runs `getElementById` to look for the audio player.

Another issue is that my page has at least three audio players, for three or more recordings. `id="audioplayer{{$index}}"` dynamically generates a unique element ID for each audio player. The button passes through which audio player the user selected. The handler then gets that unique audio player by element ID and sets the `playbackRate`.